# query class img in react but value is null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to programmatically toggle a class on an image tag inside my react application, but I can not figure out how.

```js
let imgs = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-intro');
}, []);

console.log(imgs);
imgs[1].classList.toggle('hide');

return (
  <img ref={imgs} className='img-intro hide' src='' />
  <img ref={imgs} className='img-intro hide' src='' />
  <img ref={imgs} className='img-intro hide' src='' />
);
```

I am encountering the following error when trying to use `React.useRef` on multiple image tags and when trying to use the query selector.

[image: browser console error]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chao ban, can you check out this code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vxfxn3?file=src%2FApp.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const imgs = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    imgs.current = document.querySelectorAll('.img-intro');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const a = imgs.current?.[1].classList.toggle;
          console.log(a);
          debugger;
          imgs.current?.[1]?.classList?.toggle('hide');
        }}
      >
        toggle
      </button>

      <img
        style={{ border: '1px solid red', width: '50px', height: '50px' }}
        className="img-intro hide"
        src=""
      />
      <img
        style={{ border: '1px solid red', width: '50px', height: '50px' }}
        className="img-intro hide"
        src=""
      />
      <img
        style={{ border: '1px solid red', width: '50px', height: '50px' }}
        className="img-intro hide"
        src=""
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i add "?" in imgs.curent and it work,thanks

Comment: whethe we can asign it(imgs.curent? ) like variable

Answer (score 0):

The `imgs` ref should be assigned like this

`ims.current = document.querySelectorAll('.img-intro');`

For best practice, you should rename `imgs` to `imgRefs`

```js
let imgs = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // assigned useRef variable
  imgs.current = document.querySelectorAll('.img-intro');
}, []);

// access to useRef variable
console.log(imgs.current[1]);
imgs.current[1].classList.toggle('hide');

return (
  <img ref={imgs} className='img-intro hide' src='' />
  <img ref={imgs} className='img-intro hide' src='' />
  <img ref={imgs} className='img-intro hide' src='' />
);
```

Take a look at [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#usage) usage

Comment: I tried your way but value of imgs.current is Nodelist with leght = 0 event thought i have 3 tag img

Comment: where are your `img` tags placed

Comment: if you want to access to the useRef variable you also need to access to the `current`  ex: `imgs.current[0]`

Comment: I tried this way but it can't work, so i add '?' in syntax  imgs.current?.[1] and it work